# how do I call a javascript function() in a div style tag

Tags: javascript, html, function, styles

I am trying to do a progress bar and it seems that I have to call a javascript function in my div style tag to determine the length of my progress bar based on:
 https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Progress Bar With Label</h2>
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="getme" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="value()" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: function value()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function value(){

       20

      }
     </script>

</div>
```

However it seems to not be able to work the same like others whereby I can just place a function in it in a div tag. (Eg. onclick= "function value()")

Comment: why not just use a progress tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Comment: Is that your full JS code? You need to return a value when the function runs

Comment: @Pete how do I input my function name in the value = ""

Comment: @TobiasBarsnes its not my full js code, but lets say i return the value of 20, how can i ensure that it runs my function on the style=""

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s03t75wf/ - you can just change `this.value` on click if you use a progress bar

Comment: You can only trigger javascript code from dom events.

The 'onclick' assignment you refer to is doing just that - your function is getting triggered from the 'click' event.

A way to change an attribute value on an element would be to bind to the load event,  get the element, and set the value there.



This is why there are frameworks like react or vue, which allow in-definition assignment of attributes, which is what you're attempting here.